# When I get rewarded with a crystal and already have 3, do I forfeit the reward?

Tags: mage-knight

When I get crystal rewards (for example via rolling dice after winning in some adventure sites), do I forfeit them if I already have 3, or can I reroll?

Answer (score 4):

Effectively, **you're forced to use the new crystal immediately.** You gain a mana token of the crystal's colour directly into your Play area.

From [the rules](http://wizkidsgames.com/wp-content/uploads/mage/MK_rulebook_ENG_searchable-mar2012.pdf), page 5, under **"Gain" Effects**:

> If an effect tells you to gain a crystal, take a mana token of the corresponding color and put it in your Inventory. If you already have three crystals of that color, gain a mana token of that color to your Play area instead.

Comment: This (correctly) implies that if you're unable to use the mana token of that color it will be "forfeit" at the end of your turn.  In that sense the OP's assumption was right.